# dpkg: overwrite file in another package

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I am making a DEB package that relies on `avahi-daemon`.

I need to set its configuration, but I got this error message:

```
trying to overwrite '/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf', which is also in package avahi-daemon 0.8-5+deb11u2
```

What is the standard procedure to do such configuration?  I do not want to use `--force-overwrite` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to ship a replacement `avahi-daemon.conf` (potentially losing other changes made by the local system administrator), you need to [declare that your package replaces `avahi-daemon`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#overwriting-files-in-other-packages). This is valid even for partial replacements. Add an entry in `debian/control`:

```
Replaces: avahi-daemon
```

Another approach which might be better is to make your changes in a `postinst` maintainer script.

Comment: So, it is OK to use `Depends: avahi-daemon` and `Replaces: avahi-daemon` **together**? @Stephan Kitt

Comment: Yes, it’s OK (even if surprising).

Comment: It's been a very long time since I had to do something like this but I would have thought that this is one of the things that `dpkg-divert` is for.  See also [Dpkg Diversions](https://wiki.debian.org/DpkgDiversions).